# How do I simplify a conditional with multiple or statements?

Tags: shell-script

I am writing a shell script that checks to see if a parameter matches a string. There are around 20 of them and more may need to be added in the future.

Currently the way I have it written it's hard to read and would be cumbersome to update. I'm not very familiar with shell scripting so I'm not sure of the best way to simplify this and make it easier to manage.

```
if [ $4 =="CRITICAL" ] && [[ $2 == "foo" || $2 == "bar" || $2 == "foo" || $2 == "bar" || $2 == "foo" || $2 == "bar" || $2 == "foo" || $2 == "bar" || $2 == "foo" || $2 == "bar" || ]]
  VARIABLE=1
fi
```

Foo and bar would all be different strings in the above script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [[ $4 == CRITICAL && $2 =~ ^(a|b|c|d|e|f|g)$ ]]; then
  VARIABLE=1
fi
```

BTW, unquoted variables and positional parameters are safe to use inside `[[ ... ]]`, but not in `[ ... ]`.  In other words, your `[ $4 == "CRITICAL" ]` should be `[ "$4" == "CRITICAL" ]`.

Also, `CRITICAL` doesn't need to be quoted at all above .  It's a fixed string, with no spaces or shell metacharacters.   If it was a fixed string that did need quoting for any reason, it's best to use single quotes.

Single quotes are for fixed strings, double-quotes are for when you want to interpolate variables, command substitutions, etc into a string.

Comment: What could go wrong in leaving it unquoted? I tested this unquoted and it worked as expected. The first conditional actually came from the original Apache script which I'm now modifying.

Comment: to start with, syntax error if $4 is empty.  unquoted, if $4 was empty, it would be `[ == "CRITICAL" ]`.  quoted, it is `[ "" == "CRITICAL" ]`.   `==` requires two operands.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I wonder why it was written this way to begin with. Thanks for your suggestions, I'll make the changes.

Comment: it was probably written that way because lots of people are sloppy when it comes to properly quoting variables in shell scripts.  either because they don't know they should, or because they are lazy, or they just assume "nothing could possibly ever go wrong because my code is perfect and I have thought of all possible variations that might occur".  this last reason is, of course, highly credible and a sign of supreme skill.

Comment: Lol I would imagine the last reason is the most common. So if I had a string "foo bar" where you have `a|b|c`, etc, would it become `^("foo bar"|"bar foo"|"foo bar")$`? I would assume you would not want to use quotes, as it looks like plain regex.

Comment: yep. a,b,c...g are just placeholders for longer patterns.   and correct, quotes aren't needed there.  in fact, you don't want them there unless the pattern you're matching includes quote character(s).

Comment: Except in `zsh`, unquoted parameter expansion are not safe to use inside `[[...]]` on the right hand side of the `=`/`==` operator when you intend those to be equality comparison. `[[ $a = "$b" ]]` is an equality operator, but `[[ $a = $b ]]` is a pattern matching operator. For the `=~` operator, the behaviour varies between shells (and even versions thereof like for bash)

Comment: In Bash, regex patterns for use with `=~` matching should be placed in variables which should be used unquoted. This prevents the need to include quotes in the pattern to protect spaces, etc., and prevents the pattern from potentially being evaluated as a simple string. `pattern="^(foo bar|bar foo|baz qux)$"; if [[ $4 == CRITICAL && $2 =~ $pattern ]]`. Also note that the question is tagged [tag:shell-script] and not  as a specific shell, so it might not be safe to assume that the OP's shell supports regex matching.

Answer (score 7):

In standard shell, you can use `case`, which supports alternation:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$4" = CRITICAL ]; then
        case $2 in
        foo|bar|doo|quux)
                VARIABLE=1
                ;;
        esac
fi
```

If spending five lines on the `case` is too verbose, write it on one:

```
 case $2 in foo|bar|doo|quux) VARIABLE=1;; esac
```

Note that `==` is not standard in `[ .. ]`, but it's supported in Bash and ksh.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of a `case` statement coupled with functions perhaps?

```
function a_func){ ... }
function b_func(){ ... }

case "${1}" in
  "${4}" == "CRITICAL" && $(echo "${2}" | egrep -n 'a|b|c|d|e|f|g') -gt 0))
    a_func ;;
  *)
    b_func ;;
esac
```

While a pseudo code, it should steer the course